# Qt Creator: How to add new theme styles?

Tags: macos, themes, qt-creator

I want to add this theme to my Qt Creator but i'm not sure how to add it. The only instruction the website give for mac OS is below. I copied and pasted this code into my terminal but nothing happened. Please help.

```
cp SublimeMaterial.xml ~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/styles/
```

The link and image of the theme style is below:

https://github.com/foxoman/sublimematerial

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Copy *SublimeMaterial.xml* to `%QtInstallDir%/Qt%VersionNumber%/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/styles`
2. Restart *Qt Creator*
3. Go to `Tools/Options/Text Editor/Font & Colors` and select *SublimeMaterial* from the drop-down list
4. Click *OK*

`%QtInstallDir%` is the folder where Qt is installed.

`Qt%VersionNumber%` is the folder with your version of Qt.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I didn't know what cp was but now i got it.